# Как редактировать мультисайт wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-multisite

У меня проблема, есть задача отредактировать мультисайт wordpress.

---

Пример:

Есть сайты

1. https://bt-one.ru/
2. https://spb.bt-one.ru/
3. https://voronezh.bt-one.ru/

4..5..6..7..8 и т.д
Сайтов около 30

Как вы могли заметить сайты почти одинаковые.

---

Задача состоит в том что надо поменять контент страниц на всех поддоменах (написал выше) в том числе добавить новые кастомные поля для страниц, отредактировать картинки из админки и чтобы изменения применились на все страницы поддоменов.

Думал изменить таблицу базы данных wp_posts (копировать ее на все остальные таблицы wp_6_posts, wp_7_posts, wp_8_posts, wp_9_posts и т.д) **НО** На некоторых страницах разный контент

Например страница - https://bt-one.ru/kontakty/ отличается от https://spb.bt-one.ru/kontakty/ (также еще в некоторых местах разные заголовки)

Вопрос: Как мне можно изменить контент на всех страницах поддоменов не затрагивая некоторые страницы? Есть ли какие нибуть плагины? Или мне все это вручную делать для каждого поддомена?

Comment: Можно не таблицу копировать, а смотреть изменения БД и повторить / внести данные изменения на всех остальных. Т.е. будут INSERT / UPDATE, а не полное копирование таблицы.

Comment: Ни вкоем случае не копировать таблицы. И вообще не лезь в базу. А задача не понятна.